# Enable Qt Creator to create core files when in run mode?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, coredump

I am running a GUI program in Qt and whenever I exit the program the error message in the Qt Creator terminal is

> "The program has unexpectedly finished. /.../../.. exited with code 0".

However when I run this same executable through the Linux terminal and exit the program I get a segfault(core dumped) and consequently a core file. I was wondering if it is possible to enable the creation of core files by running the program from Qt Creator (not in debug mode, just build and run mode)?

Answer (score 2):

Creating core files depends on the operating system rather than a single program or some IDE.
Try running

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

on the shell before running qtcreator. Then you can try launch your program.
If you need more details take a look at the man page of **bash**.
Good luck!

Comment: If your system uses _systemd_ take a look at the command `coredumpctl`.